# how to simplify an xml document.

Tags: xml

I have node on a drupal site called 'artists' I've export all these nodes into an xml document using a module. 
The code looks like this:

```
<node>
<vid>304</vid>
<uid>102</uid>
<title>Hanne Hoejfeldt</title>
<log></log>
<status>1</status>
<comment>2</comment>
<promote>0</promote>
<sticky>0</sticky>
<vuuid>060c67ab-fea1-484e-9a5b-f551840d48b1</vuuid>
<ds_switch></ds_switch>
<nid>304</nid>
<type>artist</type>
<language>und</language>
<created>1352825291</created>
<changed>1438587438</changed>
<tnid>0</tnid>
<translate>0</translate>
<uuid>03eb47d0-fb45-4ad5-bde2-0c5b762d8506</uuid>
<revision_timestamp>1438587438</revision_timestamp>
<revision_uid>11</revision_uid>
<body>
  <und _numeric_keys="1">
    <n0>
      <value>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.538em;&quot;&gt;Hanne Hoejfeldt was born in 1949 in Hjorring, Denmark.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;b style=&quot;line-height: 1.538em; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;&quot;&gt;Solo Exhibitions&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;1994 Pandrup Town Hall, Pandrup, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2006 Nibe Museum, Nibe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;Group Exhibitions&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;1997 Billedstedet, Fosdalen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;1998 Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Kirsten Kjaers Museum of Art, Frostrup, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;1999 Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery SO-TO, Aalborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Danish Art-Fair, Viborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2000 Gallery Knud Grothe, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Billedstedet, Fosdalen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2001 Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Bronderslev Highschool, Bronderslev, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2002 Gallery Knud Grothe, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Billedstedet, Fosdalen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2003 Gallery Knud Grothe, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Jarsbo, Aarthus, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Artgallery Odense, Odense, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Varmegalleriet, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2004 Artgallery Odense, Odense, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2005 Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Billedstedet, Fosdalen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Fussingo Castle, Fussingo, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Jarsbo, Aarthus, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galerie Horn, Lolland, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Vejle, Vejle, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Artgallery Odense, Odense, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2006 Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Jarsbo, Aarthus, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Copenhagen, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2007 Gallery Knud Grothe, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Jarsbo, Aarthus, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Copenhagen, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galerie Horn, Lolland, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2008 Gallery Knud Grothe, Copenhagen, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galleri Fyns Arthouse, Ringe, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Jarsbo, Aarthus, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Inuit, Aalborg, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Gilberg, Fredericia, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Artgallery Odense, Odense, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Gallery Annorlunda, xxxx, Sweden&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;GINA Gallery of International Na෥ Art, Tel Aviv, Israel&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;2009 Fete de L&amp;#39;Art Naif, Verneuil, Paris, France&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Katowice Festival, Katowice, Poland&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;text-indent: 0.5in; margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Magdeburg Festival, Magdeburg, Germany&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p style=&quot;text-indent: 0.5in; margin-bottom: 0in&quot;&gt;&lt;font face=&quot;Arial, sans-serif&quot;&gt;Galleri Gilberg, Fredericia, Denmark&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</value>
      <summary></summary>
      <format>full_html</format>
    </n0>
  </und>
</body>
<field_profile_photo>
  <und _numeric_keys="1">
    <n0>
      <fid>1166</fid>
      <uid>1</uid>
      **<filename>Hanne_Hoejfeldt.jpg</filename>**
      <uri>public://Hanne_Hoejfeldt.jpg</uri>
      <filemime>image/jpeg</filemime>
      <filesize>6406</filesize>
      <status>1</status>
      <timestamp>1360494813</timestamp>
      <type>image</type>
      <uuid>8f0d8a1c-721c-47eb-b237-01c4b76f55a1</uuid>
      <field_file_image_alt_text _numeric_keys="1"></field_file_image_alt_text>
      <field_file_image_title_text _numeric_keys="1"></field_file_image_title_text>
      <rdf_mapping _numeric_keys="1"></rdf_mapping>
      <image_dimensions>
        <width>140</width>
        <height>140</height>
      </image_dimensions>
      <alt>Hanne Hoejfeldt</alt>
      <title>Hanne Hoejfeldt</title>
      <width>140</width>
      <height>140</height>
    </n0>
  </und>
</field_profile_photo>
<field_country>
  <und _numeric_keys="1">
    <n0>
      <lid>199</lid>
      <name></name>
      <street></street>
      <additional></additional>
      <city></city>
      <province></province>
      <postal_code></postal_code>
      <country>dk</country>
      <latitude>0.000000</latitude>
      <longitude>0.000000</longitude>
      <source>0</source>
      <is_primary>0</is_primary>
      <province_name></province_name>
      **<country_name>Denmark</country_name>**
      <fax></fax>
      <phone></phone>
    </n0>
  </und>
</field_country>
<field_country_location>
  <und _numeric_keys="1">
    <n0>
      <nid>1528</nid>
    </n0>
  </und>
</field_country_location>
<field_first_name_artist>
  <und _numeric_keys="1">
    <n0>
      **<value>Hanne</value>**
      <format type="NULL"></format>
      <safe_value>Hanne</safe_value>
    </n0>
  </und>
</field_first_name_artist>
<field_last_name_artist>
  <und _numeric_keys="1">
    <n0>
      <**value>Hoejfeldt</value>**
```

However I only want the values that are within the tags

```
 <title>Hanne Hoejfeldt</title>, <value>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.538em;&quot;&gt;Hanne Hoejfeldt was born in 1949 in Hjorring, Denmark.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;... </value>, <filename>Hanne_Hoejfeldt.jpg</filename>,  <country_name>Denmark</country_name>,   <value>Hanne</value, <value>Hoejfeldt</value>
```

How do I extract only these values from the xml file?

Comment: We need more context here. What's the tool you are using/plan to use? XSLT, XQuery, some programming language (what is it)?

Comment: I don't know what tool to use. I have an xml document I can open in notepad++ and I need to extract only some of the data. How should I go about this?

Comment: As said by @har07, you need to tell more. There are many solutions for a single problem or issue, but out of them we need the best and least troublesome.

Comment: 1. Like you can use a simple XML DB and store this document in it, then using XQuery you can fetch the required nodes. 2. Say you are using Java, then this can also be done... like on with XSLT, VB.net, C#...

Comment: i know how to program in php. Is there a way to do it using php?

Answer (score 0):

Transforming one XML to another XML is a natural task for XSLT. For example, using [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <!-- create one root element, 
         and process elements in the source XML as content of the root -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy required elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*[name()=('title','value','filename','country_name')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove unnecessary elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**<kbd>[`Demo`](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNg)</kbd>**

Comment: See the demo. You can use the same online tools to run the code

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => !x.HasElements && ((string)x).Trim().Length > 0).Select(y => y).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: where / how can I run this code? where do I write which tags I want?

Comment: the code above is for Visual Studio C3, but can easily be changed to Visual Studio VB.Net.